# Передача видео с компьютера на мобильные устройства

Tags: видео, передача-данных

Нам нужно совместить следующие гаджеты

1) телефоны  Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge или Samsung Galaxy S8 в количестве 25-30 штук

2) Роутер Asus RT-A­C68U или подобный

3) Планшет Apple Ip­ad 2017 128gb wifi+c­ellular или Ноутбук

Задача. При запуске видео на Планшете или Ноутбуке , оно должно одновременно проигрываться на всех смартфонах. Звук не нужен, только видео. Видео должно передаваться в хорошем качестве на расстоянии до 15 метров и не тормозить. Длина видео до 30  минут.
В телефоне должна стоять программа для воспроизведения видео через очки виртуальной реальности.
Что делать?
Мой вопрос о совместимости

Comment: о совместимости чего у вас вопрос?

Comment: а телефоны клеятся на стену и  получается большой-большой экран?

Comment: Как совместить все гаджеты. Телефоны используются для обучающей программы в школе и устанавливаются в Очки VR